# querySelectorAll not working in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

i'm new with Coffeescript and how it's works on RoR, so i'm having a hard time solving this problem:

I have a file called candidate.coffee in my asset's file that was generated in a scaffold command. I coded this:

```
masks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-mask]')
alert masks.length
```

In candidate's view, I coded in form_for some of theses inputs, all of them with data-mask attrib.

```
<%= f.label :cep, "CEP" %>
<%= f.text_field :cep, data: { mask: 'cep' } %> 
...
```

So, the problem is: I know Rails reach candidate.coffee because Alert function works, and it gave me 0 (zero) length. But I don't know why document.querySelectorAll is not working.

I read that all .coffee files in assets are compiled, but I didn't find out how Rails related .coffee files with view files. That means, this code in candidate.coffee

```
masks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-mask]')
```

should search in all view files in my project? Said that, I did use any kind of HTML tag as

```
<script src=... script>
```

in my view files, and didn't change my Application.js.

How can I solve this? And someone can help with my question about how Rails related functions in .coffee/js file with views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure the document is fully loaded before that script is run. Try adding

```
$ ->
```

at the top of the file and ensure you indent the rest of the code properly, as that is the coffeescript equivalent of document.ready()

Comment: Holy shit, it works! I knew that it was something stupid. Thanks!